# get_post_meta() empty in preview WHEN custom post is published

Tags: post-meta

So my client managed to find some (bug?), when custom post is published and he previews post all information what is posted with custom meta boxes is inaccessible. When I started debugging I found that in this case get post meta returns empty. Someone know why system acts this way.

And yes, when i look at post not prview all information shows fine. And before posting get_post_meta() works okay. Only in this case where post is pubished and preview is clicked.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. It is possible that you are not saving the custom meta fields for drafts. I've seen that frequently. Can you post the code you are using to save the post meta values?

Comment: same issue here but more specifically post_meta isnt updated to new value in preview when post is published.